# What is the best way to define the same fmt::formatter for multiple types?

Tags: c++, fmt

I am attempting to write a custom formatter for a `Vector<VType>` vector.  Depending on build settings, this could be a `std::vector`, or a `__gnu_debug::vector`.  Both these types present an identical external interface, and I would like to format both types identically.  Also importantly though, only of of the type types will be properly defined at compile time.

What is the proper way to achieve this?  I tried something along the following lines, however it did not result in creation of the formatters I needed.

```
struct DataClass;

template<>
template<template<typename> typename VectorType>
struct fmt::formatter<VectorType<DataClass>> {
   //...
};
```

Comment: If you can use fmtlib, why not just use [`fmt/ranges.h`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/ranges.h)?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Part of the output includes aggregate statistics, like the cumulative sum of a specific field in VType as well as information for each VType.  At least in the trivial examples I am finding, fmt ranges cannot handle that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that std::vector is defined as `template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector`, so the lookup fails since the formatter is expecting a `VectorType` with only 1 template parameter.  One solution is to unconstrain the number of template arguments:

```
template<>
template<template<typename...> typename VectorType>
struct fmt::formatter<VectorType<DataClass>> {
    //...
}
```

I would be interested in a better solution to this problem, since I could easily see this becoming a problem in the future where the formatter is now too unconstrained.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
#ifdef USE_GNU_DEBUG_VECTOR
template <typename T>
using Vector = __gnu_debug::vector<T>;
#else
template <typename T>
using Vector = std::vector<T>;
#endif

template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<Vector<T>> {
   //...
};
```

where `USE_GNU_DEBUG_VECTOR` is controlled by your build settings.